# Is it possible to stack multiple bitmap images on top of each other?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not a coder so I was just wondering.

EXAMPLE
Each image will contain a puzzle piece, and has a blank/see through background (allowing a layering effect).

The user goes through a process to build the puzzle, with the ability to choose different pieces.

The bitmap image is called when the user selects a new puzzle piece and a string is created. Each letter in the string calls a bitmap image and the whole string itself create the users puzzle.

Has this been done before? What can be used to build this?

EDIT:
I'm wondering if, for a site of thousands of images where each image is called, that this method would save a few kb per image and speed up a website

Answer (score 2):

It certainly is possible. The requirements:

- Each bitmap has to support transparency. PNG is the standard route these days.
- You need to use CSS to overlay each image. There's several possible routes, but the most useful one (which I used) is called "absolute positioning". With it, you specify exactly where within an area each image appears. Then it's a simple matter of choosing overlapping regions for each image.

I whipped up a quick proof-of-concept here:

http://jsfiddle.net/acy51ond/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Would this method of overlaying png images save space and speed up a website vs having a complete image for each called image. Wondering for a site of thousands of images

Comment: No. This stacking is just for display purposes; it has nothing to do with storing images. If you want to save space, you want to look into compression.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of fun to play with the idea.

Still a little crude but it's a start.  The way I would do it is create the page with PHP mainly to initialize the JS vars.

It will accommodate any number of pieces.  Just add more divs with an id of "p" plus the number of divs.  And expand the arrays and create the image.

The init() routine gets all the divs with an id that starts with a "p".  And cross references the div id number with the location in the in the p[] array.  This way as long as other div ids do not start with a p it auto expands and other divs do not affect the coding. The default styles are initialized here as well.  No CSS (just HTML) is needed for the divs.  The divs could be added to the HTML in the init routine

To finish it of you would need to add a function to select the puzzle piece in the toggle() on routine.

This is tested code.  Just copy and paste in to an html file, save the images, and it will function.

[To see the page working Click Here](http://ispeedlink.com/so/puzzle/)

Instructions:
 
Click on a box and a puzzle piece will appear
 
Each time you click the box, it will toggle  the piece on and off

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Overlapp Images</title>
<style type="text/css">
#contents{position:relative;height:500px;width:500px;}
</style>
</head><body><div id="contents">
<div id="p1" onclick="toggle(1)"></div>
<div id="p2" onclick="toggle(2)"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var onOff = new Array;
onOff.push(0);
var xref = new Array;
xref.push(0);
var width = ['100px','73px','100px'];
var height = ['100px','100px','73px'];
var t = ['100','0px','80px'];
var left = ['','15px','0px'];
function init(){
var did='';
var ndx=0;
  for (var div=0; div<p.length; div++){
    did = p[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "p"){
        ndx = parseInt(did.substring(1));
        p[div].style.border = '1px solid #000';
        p[div].style.width = width[0];
        p[div].style.height = height[0];
        p[div].style.top = t[0] * (ndx - 1) + 'px';
        p[div].style.left = left[0];
        p[div].style.position = 'absolute';
        onOff.push(0);
        xref.push(ndx);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(xref);
function toggle(id){
  if (onOff[id]!=1){
    p[xref[id]].style.backgroundImage = 'url(puzzle' + id + '.png)';
    p[xref[id]].style.border = 0;
    p[xref[id]].style.width = width[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.height = height[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.top = t[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.left = left[id];
    onOff[id]=1;
  }
  else{
    p[xref[id]].style.backgroundImage = '';
    p[xref[id]].style.border = '1px solid #f00';
    p[xref[id]].style.width = width[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.height = height[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.top = t[id];
    p[xref[id]].style.left = left[id];
    onOff[id]=0;
  }
}
window.onload = init;
//]]></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: There is no limit to the number of puzzle images you can use.  A function that selects which image get placed will take care of that.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant that the images needed to be overlaid on top of each other, like the example above.

Comment: Not a problem, just change the position `var t = ['100','0px','80px'];
var left = ['','15px','0px'];` top is labeled t because top conflicts with JavaScript reserved word.  I just wanted to show that it is flexible and when they are not on top one another you can see what's happening.  You position them where ever based on the values set in the t and left arrays.